# How to find a subset whose minimum distance between elements is greater than a certain value and whose sum of values of elements is maximized?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I'm trying to solve an algorithm problem here.

There are n distinct elements in an array, and their positions are from x_1 to x_n. Each element has an individual value of p (so for the i-th element in the array, its position would be x_i, and its p value would be p_i).

First you choose an arbitrary subset S of the given array (so 0 <= |S| <= n) such that the distance between any two elements is greater than k (so every {x_i,x_j} ⊆ S must have |xi−xj| > k). Then you have to find the maximum sum of p values of any pair of elements in such subset S.

Any ideas on how I could do this in polynomial time?

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What do you mean by "find the maximum sum of p values of any pair of elements in such subset S"? Are you required to find only one pair(i,j) in S whose p_i + p_j is maximum?

Comment: There's a suitable O(nk)-time dynamic program. For inspiration, you can look at the one for maximum-sum subsequence with no adjacent elements.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic programming

At every element, you have a choice to include it or not. If you include it you can't include any of the last k elements, current value + max value at current index - k. If you don't include the current element the last index max value will be the current element max value.

for(let i=0;i<x.length;++i)
DP[i] = Math.max(DP[i-k]+x[i],DP[i-1])